# Default style for a sheet in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to work out how to specify a default CellStyle for a Sheet using POI with XSSF files.

I understand that if I call getCellStyle(0) on a Workbook, I get back the default style for the Workbook, and can make modifications as desired. I can also call setDefaultColumnStyle(index, style) on a Sheet, which will allow me to set the default style for new cells created in a particular column. But short of iterating through *all columns* and calling this method on each one (which would be terribly wasteful), I can't see there being any way of setting a default style for all cells of a particular sheet. (Setting it on a column-by-column basis is fine if one knows in advance what columns a user may choose to populate, but it's not ideal if a user could edit any cell in the Workbook, and a default should still apply.)

Am I missing something? Is there any way to set the default CellStyle for a specific Sheet? Thanks.

Comment: I posted another related (but different) question recently, and the linked answer by Axel provides some very useful information relevant to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39688315/5695326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use pre-defined excel template with default cell style for the sheet.
- customize your sheet (other formatting, business logic which is user specific) in your java code.